# Finding factors of integers

Tags: java, while-loop

I tried to create a simple program that finds all divisors of a number. I was instructed to store every divisor into a string and use a while loop. I don't know why, but my program does not run. It compiles without errors, but gives no output.

```
import static java.lang.System.*;

public class Divisors
{
    public static String getDivisors( int number )
    {
        String divisors="";
        int n=1;
        while(n < number)
        {
            if (number % n==0)
            {
                divisors +=" "+ n;
            }
        }
        return number+ " has divisors:"+ divisors;
    }
}
```

Here is my tester class:

import static java.lang.System.*;

```
public class Lab09f
{
    public static void main( String args[] )
    {
        Divisors d = new Divisors();

        out.println(d.getDivisors(10));
        out.println(d.getDivisors(45));
        out.println(d.getDivisors(14));
        out.println(d.getDivisors(1024));
        out.println(d.getDivisors(1245));
        out.println(d.getDivisors(33));
        out.println(d.getDivisors(65535));
    }
}
```

Comment: You never increment `n`, so `n < number` is always `true`.  You have an infinite loop.

Comment: You can optimize this a bit... When `number % n == 0`, you found not one, but 2 divisors: `n` and `number/n`. If you add both of these, you can then iterate until Sqrt(number) only (`while (n < Math.sqrt(number))`. You may also need to check whether `n == number/n` to avoid adding a divisor twice :)

Answer (score 4):

```
while(n < number)
    {
        if (number % n==0)
        {
            divisors +=" "+ n;
        }
        n++;
    }
    return number+ " has divisors:"+ divisors;
}
```

you were not adding to your n so was looping forever

Answer (score 0):

You need to increment n:

```
public class Divisors
{
    public static String getDivisors( int number )
    {
        String divisors="";
        int n=1;
        while(n < number)
        {
            if (number % n==0)
            {
                divisors +=" "+ n++;
            }
        }
        return number+ " has divisors:"+ divisors;
    }
}
```

Comment: Won't work. n should be incremented in any case, not only if the condition is true.